# Do work from Linux

Tags: cross-platform

I am a programmer who likes to be on my old  Linux box . I am also getting programming work which are in Apple and Windows ( and also android, and also embedded, and also cloud). Now I don't want to go into the internals of these 2 OS , but if I get work which is purely logic based and language based , say some c++ or shell scripting etc in these 2 OS then I want to do them to earn money , sitting infront of my linux box. Question is can I work on my Linux machine and deliver stuffs to my clients which will run on these 2 OS . If yes what I have to do and what software, IDE etc I have to install in my Linux machine. Do I need to install a VM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com) RAD IDE will let you develop on Linux and create apps for OS X and Windows. But you'll really want to test on those OS's before you send anything to your clients. It's easy to run Windows in a VM on Linux, but OS X licensing requires a Mac.